# How to prevent multi sql query in one page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, mysqli

i have a database table like this:

**company**

[image]

In my ındex page i have 3 modules.

1. Gold companies (gold.php)

   ```
   $db->where('gold','1');
   $company = $db->get('company');
   foreach ($company as $gold)
     { 
      echo $gold['name'] ;
     }
   ```
2. Companies order by date (last-added) (last.php)

   ```
   $db->orderby('date','desc');
   $company = $db->get('company');
   foreach ($company as $date)
     { 
      echo $date['name'] ;
     }
   ```
3. Online companies (online.php)

   ```
   $db->where('online','1');
   $company = $db->get('company');
   foreach ($company as $online)
     { 
      echo $online['name'] ;
     }
   ```

And here is my index page

```
     include ( "gold.php" );
     include ( "last.php" );
     include ( "online.php" );
```

**My question:
There is 3 modules in one page and 3 queries in one page. For the best performance of mysql, how can i use these queries? Can i use only one query for all of this modules.**

Comment: Is this a non-problem?  My typical web page has a dozen queries, and the page is "fast enough".

Comment: i am worried about if i have a fault in my code for performance. If all of you says there is no problem, then i ll be happy and go on with my style.

Comment: Selecting dozens of rows, assuming a tiny table _and/or_ a good index, takes a trivial amount of time.  Selecting hundreds of rows -- why would you inflict such a large page on the user?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking 3 different questions:

1. All companies who are gold in natural order
2. All companies in date order
3. All companies who are online in natural order

That's 3 different questions. You will have to come to a compromise on the ordering -

You could ask:

Fetch me all the companies who are either gold OR online (WHERE gold=1 OR online=1)

This will fetch back a combined list in natural order of gold companies and online companies (and gold online companies).

You could parse the results as you output them spitting the gold companies into one list and the online into another list, but what to do with the gold online companies - currently they go in both lists)

Now it's starting to feel a bit messy. Let's think of it another way...

You're already asking to fetch back ALL the companies so, ask that one question. Now, as you parse the results you spit the gold companies into the gold list, the online companies into the online list and all the companies in the all company list)

The only difference is your gold and online lists will be ordered by date. Is this acceptable?

tbh, so long as your gold and online columns are indexed and the results are small or paged, the overhead for the three queries should be negligible and makes for much more easy to read code / modular code.

Comment: This is only a  sample data, actually not a specific question. I want to learn basic logical way of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
    SELECT name, online, gold
      FROM company
     ORDER BY date
```

Then in your php code when you loop trought result(assuming your variable names):
1. display only when `$gold['gold'] == 1`
2. nothing to change
1. display only when `$online['online'] == 1`

Comment: unfurtunately it is hard to use through results, This is only a sample data, I want to learn basic logical way of this stuff in big projects.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without having a clear understanding of the web page ergonomics.

If you load everything upfront (because you need everything upfront), then I would create the object pool with only one query, given that the amount of objects to load is reasonable (it seems to be your case)

If users load content progressively, it would be worth inserting a few ajax endpoints in your front and back ends so you can retrieve data on-demand, when it's really needed.

Comment: What do ou mean by object pool, can you give a sample object code?

Comment: @Bagova in `$company = $db->get('company');`, `$company` is your object pool